# GITLAB CI/CD Improving Pipeline Speed with cache or Artifacts?

Tags: caching, gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci

I really don't understand how cache works and how i can really speed up my CI/CD. I would like to just make it run in less than 2 minutes but all i got is a 30m/40m/1h pipeline.

I have already tried a lot of caching techniques (Global cache, per job cache)
I am not going to write all of them here (i am working on this 3 days by now so i tried a lot of stuff and read a lot of stuff too..).

The project is a .NET MVC Project with some static bundling through NPM.

The CI/CD is running on a Windows Server 2008 R2.
No docker images. Just gitlab-runner inside the C:\gitlab_runner folder and all the tools are natively installed on the machine tagged as `deploy-vmdev`

(The project is called `Iom.Site` and it is saved inside the `Iom.Site` folder)

The best i was able to do was this (but it runs on average of 30m and sometimes it breaks up because depedencies caches, node_modules and packages, aren't present.):

```
stages:
  - install_dependencies
  - build_app
  - deploy

#Execute dependencies only on package-lock.json e packages.config changes
install_dependencies:
  stage: install_dependencies
  only:
    changes:
      - Iom.Site/package-lock.json
      - Iom.Site/packages.config
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
      - Iom.Site/node_modules
      - packages/
  tags:
    - deploy-vmdev
  script:
    - if(!((nuget sources) -like "*Promoscience*").Length -gt 0) { nuget sources add -Name Promoscience -Source http://nupromo.promoscience.com/nuget };
    - nuget restore
    - cd Iom.Site
    - npm install

#Bundling through gulp npm packages static files (SCSS, JS,..)
#Copying .\site\content inside .\dist folder at root for packaging
build_static_files:
  stage: build_app
  only:
    changes:
      - Iom.Site\scripts\bundle\**\*
      - Iom.Site\scripts\react\**\*
      - Iom.Site\scss\**\*
      - ".gitlab-ci.yml"
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
      - Iom.Site/node_modules
    policy: pull
  tags:
    - deploy-vmdev
  script:
    - gulp build
    - cd ..
    - Copy-Item Iom.Site\content .\dist\
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - .\dist
    when: on_success
    expire_in: 30 days

#Building .NET App through MSBUILD. Msbuild profile saves the output in .\dist folder
#for packaging the whole app
build_app:
  stage: build_app
  only:
    changes:
      - "**/*.cs"
      - "**/*.cshtml"
      - "**/*.config"
      - ".gitlab-ci.yml"
  tags:
    - deploy-vmdev
  script:
    - msbuild Iom.Site\Iom.Site.csproj /p:Configuration=test /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile /p:transformConfigFiles=true /p:deployOnBuild=true
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
      - packages/
    policy: pull
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - .\dist
    when: on_success
    expire_in: 30 days

#Deploying: Downloading artifacts and merging them. 
#Copying the content of dist folder inside the IIS Site
deploy_test:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - build_static_files
    - build_app
  tags:
    - deploy-vmdev
  only:
    - master
    - dev
  cache: {} 
  variables:
    SiteAppPath: "E:\\websites\\CnrIom2020"
  script:
    - echo $env:SiteAppPath
    - dir .\dist
    - Copy-Item .\dist\* $env:SiteAppPath -Recurse -Force
```

### UPDATE 1:

In the end i found this on gitlab ci wiki:

> Caching is an optimization, but it isn’t guaranteed to always work. You need to be prepared to regenerate any cached files in each job that needs them.

And changed my pipeline in this way:

```
stages:
  - build_app
  - package
  - deploy

build_static_files:
  stage: build_app
  before_script:
    - cd Iom.Site
    - if(-Not(Test-Path node_modules)){npm install} #Installiamo le dipendenze di npm solo se non presenti
  only:
    changes:
      - Iom.Site\scripts\bundle\**\*
      - Iom.Site\scripts\react\**\*
      - Iom.Site\scss\**\*
      - ".gitlab-ci.yml"
  tags:
    - deploy-vmdev
  cache:
    key: static_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
      - Iom.Site/node_modules
    policy: pull-push
  script:
    - gulp build
    - cd ..
    - Copy-Item Iom.Site\content .\dist\content -Recurse -Force #Copiamo i file statici in dist
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - .\dist
    when: on_success
    expire_in: 2 hours

build_app:
  stage: build_app
  before_script: #Installiamo le dipendenze di Nuget solo se già non presenti
    - if(-Not(Test-Path packages)){ nuget restore } 
  only:
    changes:
      - "**/*.cs"
      - "**/*.cshtml"
      - "**/*.config"
      - ".gitlab-ci.yml"
  tags:
    - deploy-vmdev
  cache:
    key: app_${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
      - packages
    policy: pull-push
  script:
    - msbuild Iom.Site\Iom.Site.csproj /p:Configuration=test /p:PublishProfile=FolderProfile /p:transformConfigFiles=true /p:deployOnBuild=true
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - .\dist
    when: on_success
    expire_in: 2 hours

package_app:
  stage: package
  dependencies:
    - build_static_files
    - build_app
  tags:
    - deploy-vmdev
  only:
    - master
    - dev
    - release
  cache: { }
  script:
    - dir .\dist
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - .\dist
    expire_in: never

deploy_test:
  stage: deploy
  dependencies:
    - package_app
  tags:
    - deploy-vmdev
  only: #TODO: When: manual
    - master
    - dev
    - release
  cache: {} 
  variables:
    SiteAppPath: "E:\\websites\\CnrIom2020"
  script:
    - echo $env:SiteAppPath
    - dir .\dist
    - Copy-Item .\dist\* $env:SiteAppPath -Recurse -Force

# deploy_release: To define
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I've noticed that can help make your runs quicker is setting the Git Clone strategy *via* the [`GIT_STRATEGY`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/configure_runners.html#git-strategy) variable.

Example:

I have a few pipelines that take files and package them in an installer which installs my employer's software. Each `.gitlab-ci.yml` configuration was split into 2-4 stages, with 1-2 jobs each stage.

Since I only needed to clone my repo on the first job, I set its `GIT_STRATEGY` to `clone` so I always start with a fresh repo. For the remaining jobs, I set `GIT_STRATEGY` to `none` which saved 30-60 seconds per job since (because of submodules).

At minimum, I was saving ~1 min and, at most, I was saving ~5 mins per configuration, per run. This also worked for me because the jobs after the first one did not require clean repos; I made modifications to the files which should persist between each run.